# Three.js Shader material how get (map) texture?

Tags: three.js

I have one problem here)
I decided to use my shader for (scene.overrideMaterial) and I need to somehow get the map texture.

```
MaterialsShader = {
uniforms: {
    time: { type: 'f', value: 0.0 },
},
vertexShader: 
    "varying vec2 vUv; \n\
    void main(){\n\
        vUv = uv;\n\
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );\n\
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;\n\
    }",
fragmentShader: [
    'varying vec2 vUv;',
    'uniform float opacity;',

    '#ifdef USE_MAP',

        'uniform sampler2D map;',

    '#endif',

    'void main(){',
        'vec3 color = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0) * opacity;',

        '#ifdef USE_MAP',

            'vec4 mapTexel = texture2D( map, vUv.xy );',

            'gl_FragColor = mapTexel;',

        '#endif',

        //'gl_FragColor.rgb = color;',

    '}'].join("\n")
}
```

But for some reason the texture itself does not exist, I get black material.

```
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( MaterialsShader.uniforms );

    uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [uniforms, THREE.UniformsLib['common'],THREE.UniformsLib['lights']] );


var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms        : uniforms,
    vertexShader    : MaterialsShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader  : MaterialsShader.fragmentShader,
});
```

How can I get a (map) texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to actually define your `map` uniform...

```
MaterialsShader = {
uniforms: {
    time: { type: 'f', value: 0.0 },
    map: { type: 't', value: yourLoadedTexture },
},
```

2) You need to define `USE_MAP` in order to enter that code segment of your shader. Either add this to the top of your shader code:

```
#define USE_MAP true
```

Or you can set a `defines` property for your shader:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms        : uniforms,
    vertexShader    : MaterialsShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader  : MaterialsShader.fragmentShader,
    map             : yourLoadedTexture,
    defines         : {
        USE_MAP: true
    }
});
```

These have the same effect.

Comment: Note that adding type to uniforms is no longer required, so you can leave out `type: 'f'` and  `type: 't'` from this solution.